# Google drive API 403 insufficent permission error (do I need a google for work account?)

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api

I would like to create an application to add folders and data inside those folders in Google Drive.

I am succesfully creating an acccess token using the `refresh_token` value. I am attempting to do a very basic file upload but its failing. I am also getting a list of files just to see is anything else working and that certainly is.

After the list of files appear I get the following error...

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media:
>   (403) Insufficient Permission' in
>   /var/www/html/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110
>
> Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php(62):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request),
>   Object(Google_Client)) 
>   1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request))
>
> 2 /var/www/html/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(174):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> 3 /var/www/html/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php(46): Google_Task_Runner->run()
>
> 4 /var/www/html/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php(593): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request))
>
> 5 /var/www/html/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Resource.php(240):
>   Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_H in
>   /var/www/html/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line
>   110

**UPDATE:** I tried this without using refresh_token too and simply using the latest access token but still getting the exact same error.

**Initially setting up access to get myself to the consent screen...**

```
require_once ('../autoload.php');
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://www.example.com/oauth2callback.php');


if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    print_r($_SESSION);
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    //$files_list = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array())->getItems();
    //echo json_encode($files_list);
} else {
    $redirect_uri = 'http:/www.example.com/google-api-php-client/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

**And then attempting to upload the file**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once ('../autoload.php');

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');



$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

// this token is obtained the first time from refresh_token, it will not be shown after the initial requrest
$refreshToken ='xxx';

$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$files_list = $service->files->listFiles(array())->getFiles();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($files_list);
echo '</pre>';
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");

DEFINE("TESTFILE", 'testfile-small.txt');
if (!file_exists(TESTFILE)) {
    $fh = fopen(TESTFILE, 'w');
    fseek($fh, 1024 * 1024);
    fwrite($fh, "!", 1);
    fclose($fh);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    // This is uploading a file directly, with no metadata associated.
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $result = $service->files->create(
        $file,
        array(
            'data' => file_get_contents(TESTFILE),
            'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
            'uploadType' => 'multipart'
        )
    );


}
```

Comment: I think you might have modified the previous scope of the file. Did you try deleting the old ~/.credentials/drive-php-quickstart.json as stated in [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php)?

Comment: yes, but honestly cannot remember what exactly it was related to or if it was something even related to the code above . If you like I can post my working code @noogui